# Related distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

> Let $F,G$ be distributions such that $F$ is zero IFF $G$ is zero. Then there is $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $F=cG$.

Can I argue this proposition from the integral definition? This is to say that given a test function $\psi$ the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\psi(x)dx=0$ only if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\psi(x)dx=0$. (Now here can I use the same test function for both integrals?).

The problem is to determine what happens when $F$ is not zero, but can't I make it zero again by means of some change of variables (like $t=x-a$)? I expect that after some change of variables both integrals will be zero again so some constants will come out after changing variables.

Comment: What do you get if $f,g$ are continuous functions ? (look at the linear functionals $f \mapsto f(a)-c f(b)$ for many $a,b,c$). Then you can do the same after replacing your distributions $F,G$ by $f = F \ast \phi, g = G \ast \phi$ for some $\phi \in C^\infty_c$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for answering, but I don't follow it. $f\rightarrow f(a)-cf(b)$ would verify the conditions of $f$ zero iff $g$ zero, but doesn't the problem goes the opposite way? I think it seems backwards because you start with $f(a)-cf(b)$, already assuming the conclusion. And in relation to the distributions, do I replace them in the integrals? Because it doesn't seem to follow from that.

Comment: The values of $a,b,c$ such that $f(a) - c f(b) = 0$ determinate $f$ up to a constant..

Comment: @reuns But shouldn't the proof be $f(a)-cg(b)$?

Comment: Am I right to assume that you want to prove that for a test function $\phi$ the condition $\langle F, \phi\rangle =0 \iff \langle G,\phi\rangle=0$ implies $G=cF$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Yes. It's correct.